# Under what conditions are background local services preferable to threads in Android?

Tags: android, android-service

By Local Service is I mean a Service that is *only* connected to by the host application.  It may use the Binder-subclass version of Services or it may use Messenger -- it doesn't matter.  Also, I'll consider only services that run on background threads although I think this applies regardless.

I have been trying to figure out the value of local services over a simple background thread.  I've seen it written many times that the background thread version somehow ties you to the Activity or Application lifecycle and is right only if your task should only run when the app is in foreground... but I don't see how this is true.  Background threads are AFAIK unrelated to the lifecycle of their creator context.  They don't `onPause` or anything like that.

Service describes a "lifecycle API" that permits external (client) control of the Service.  So you can, for example, call `stopService` and implement kill behavior in `Service.onStop` instead of writing your own API.  But the lifecycle is so trivially-simple that this seems like *more* complexity, not less.  For example, `stopService` and `onStop` don't need to be two different methods in a simple local implementation.

I'd especially like to hear of any real use cases where a local service was genuinely preferable to a thread.

Answer (score 0):

First of all service changes [killing order](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle) of your process.

For a task “fire and forget” all is pretty easy, real fun comes with thread communication. The regular Java mechanisms - pipes, shared memory, blocking queues - are available to Android applications but impose problems for the UI thread because of their tendency to block. Hence, the Android platform defines its own helpers.

BTW, "background" service by default starts in the main thread, for true background work you still have to use threads.